# How can I create a validation rule based on two picklist values and two multi-picklist fields?

Tags: formula, picklist, validation-rule, multi-select

I want to make it so that only accounts with a Type of "Client" or "Client - Group Contract" can have services. The "Type" field is a picklist, while the "Services" fields are multi-picklists. I want the multi-picklists to be blank on accounts that aren't clients.

I can do this, without errors in syntax:

```
AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL( Type, "Client")), NOT ISBLANK(Services_Purchased__c))
```

But this doesn't work:

```
AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL( Type, "Client", "Client - Group Contract"))), NOT ISBLANK(Services_Purchased__c, Services_Licensed__c)))
```

I'm getting the idea that I can't do this with ISPICKVAL, but considering the types of fields I'm working with, what else can I use?

Comment: You can check to see if the multi-select is blank with `ISBLANK(Services_Purchased__c)`

Comment: Hey if your problem has been resolved please close the question or else update the question

Comment: I've already updated the question- that was only one of two problems, unfortunately, and my main problem has yet to be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND(
NOT(OR(ISPICKVAL(Type, "Client"),ISPICKVAL(Type, "Client - Group Contract"))), 
NOT(AND(ISBLANK(Services_Purchased__c),ISBLANK(Services_Licensed__c))))
```

This translates into:

If `Type` is not "Client" or "Client-Group Contact", and both `Services_Purchased__c` and `Services_Licensed__c` are not blank, throw a validation error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put multiple options in the ISPICKVAL function. Only one at a time can be evaluated. So any other logic needs to be implemented with AND and OR statements.

If I understand correctly, this is what you want: 
"if the record is not a client (and of the 2 types), then both services fields have to be blank."

This would result in the following formula:

```
AND(
   NOT(ISPICKVAL( Type, "Client"))
   ,
   NOT(ISPICKVAL( Type, "Client - Group Contract"))
   , 
   OR(
      NOT( ISBLANK(Services_Purchased__c))
      ,
      NOT( ISBLANK(Services_Licensed__c))
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write it.

```
AND(
OR(
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Type, "Client")),
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Type, "Client - Group Contract"))),
NOT(ISBLANK(Services_Purchased__c)))
```

Give that a shot!